# Copy text string on click

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to to be able to copy a text string on click *without a button*. The text string will be inside a "span" class.

1. User hovers over text string
2. User clicks text string
3. Text string is copied to clipboard

Comment: Is it just the "without a button" part that you're stuck on? As in, you want to know how write a click event handler for a span element? (Hint: it's very, *very* similar to a click event handler on a button.) Your point 1 about the hovering seems irrelevant if nothing actually happens until the user clicks.

Comment: @matthew What exactly you want to do after copy where you want to paste?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can attach `copy` event to `<span>` element, use `document.execCommand("copy")` within event handler, set `event.clipboardData` to `span` `.textContent` with `.setData()` method of `event.clipboardData`

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span");

span.onclick = function() {
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

span.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.clipboardData) {
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", span.textContent);
    console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
  }
});
```

```html
<span>text</span>
```

Comment: How to achieve this with click on a sibling div button?

Comment: @Flo You can use the same pattern. Attach `copy` event to an element, set the clipboard data within event handler.

Comment: How do I get a hold of `clipboardData` without a `copy` event? As in from another event handler, like a click event on a separate element? The `copy` event is not firing.

Comment: This code is prone to problem if user has already selected some text. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53977796/6665568   for a full solution .

Answer (score 45):

Try this .[`document.execCommand('copy')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0hMq9toXVAhWMu48KHYpmDlcQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FexecCommand&usg=AFQjCNHKdjvU8Wln15LgsnR0kqUT_CLkxA)

1. click the element and copy the text and post with tmp input element
2. Then copy the text from this input

```js
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
```

```html
<p onclick="copy(this)">hello man</p>
```

Comment: This method works well, but how would one go about copying the text including the new lines? (\n in js , &#13;&#10; in html) I have an onclick set to a <code> tag, so users can just click and copy code, but still wont copy the new lines. I can provide more explanation and code if needed.

Comment: this worked, thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: This worked, but do you have any idea how to make it work in bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 26):

## Use the Clipboard API!

The simplest modern solution is:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(value)
```

That value can later be accessed with:

```
navigator.clipboard.readText()
```

> *NOTE*: This requires `https`, meaning it won't work on `localhost` by default

> *NOTE*: To use in an **`iframe`**, you'll need to add write (and maybe read) permissions
>
> ```
> <iframe src='' allow='clipboard-read; clipboard-write'/>
> ```

> *NOTE*: To use in an browser extension (on a webpage), you'll need either to:
>
> - call from a user triggered event (`click`...)
> - add the '`clipboardWrite`' permission to the manifest

> *NOTE*: To use in the dev console, use `copy()` instead
>
> ```
> copy('string')
> ```

[W3Schools Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_clipboard_writetext)

Comment: finally! i was about to say "has no one considered using `navigator.clipboard`???"

Comment: I'm actually surprised this is not the top answer. Clipboard API is OP

Comment: FireFox 112: `Uncaught TypeError: navigator.clipboard is undefined`

Answer (score 22):

[This is the Code pen](https://codepen.io/Ishan_Mahajan_bst/pen/dRaOoX?editors=0010).

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

```
<p style="color:wheat;font-size:55px;text-align:center;">How to copy a TEXT to Clipboard on a Button-Click</p>

<center>
<p id="p1">This is  TEXT 1</p>
<p id="p2">This is TEXT 2</p><br/>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy TEXT 1</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy TEXT 2</button>

<br/><br/><input class="textBox" type="text" id="" placeholder="Dont belive me?..TEST it here..;)" />
</center>
```

Jquery Code here

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Comment: People will reach the question on searching how to copy the text and jQuery might be an option for them even though op might not be directly benefited from my answer but a lot of community members will be

Answer (score 10):

Along with copying the text , you also have to make sure that any previously selected component remains selected after copying to clipboard.

#### Here's the full code :

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');  // Create a <textarea> element
  el.value = str;                                 // Set its value to the string that you want copied
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');                // Make it readonly to be tamper-proof
  el.style.position = 'absolute';                 
  el.style.left = '-9999px';                      // Move outside the screen to make it invisible
  document.body.appendChild(el);                  // Append the <textarea> element to the HTML document
  const selected =            
    document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0        // Check if there is any content selected previously
      ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)     // Store selection if found
      : false;                                    // Mark as false to know no selection existed before
  el.select();                                    // Select the <textarea> content
  document.execCommand('copy');                   // Copy - only works as a result of a user action (e.g. click events)
  document.body.removeChild(el);                  // Remove the <textarea> element
  if (selected) {                                 // If a selection existed before copying
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();    // Unselect everything on the HTML document
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);   // Restore the original selection
  }
};
```

ps adding the [source](https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f)

Comment: This should be correct answer. Accepted answer works wrong.

Comment: I have read both your answer and the original but somehow, can't seem to get the browser (firefox) to reselect the previously selected text once the element in question has been copied. Not sure how to debug; there's no console issues.

Answer (score 5):

The [execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method, previously used for copying text to the clipboard, has been **deprecated** and should not be used in modern web development. Instead, the [navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard) API is now the recommended way to perform clipboard operations in the browser. This API is a built-in browser Web API, which means that it is both secure and easy to integrate into your web applications without any external dependencies.

> The Clipboard API can be used to implement cut, copy, and paste
> features within a web application.

The following code snippets will only copy the content of the clicked span element.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
      let copyText = $(this)[0].textContent
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)
})
```

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    let copyText = event.target.textContent;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
  }
});
```

Feel free to customize accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

[guest271314's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071478/4122849) applied to multiple elements:

```js
spans = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
for (const span of spans) {
  span.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  span.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", span.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<span class="class">text</span>
<br>
<span class="class">text2</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='btn'>Copy</button>
```

JS

```js
document.querySelect('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   copyToClipboard('copy this text');
});
```

JS / Function:

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var selected = false;
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = text;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    if (document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0) {
        selected = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    }
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    if (selected) {
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the most suitable way to do it. It will copy all text in elements with the class "copy" in them.

```js
var copy = document.querySelectorAll(".copy"); 

for (const copied of copy) { 
  copied.onclick = function() { 
    document.execCommand("copy"); 
  };  
  copied.addEventListener("copy", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if (event.clipboardData) { 
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", copied.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    };
  });
};
```

```css
.copy {
            
  cursor: copy;
            
}
```

```html
<p><span class="copy">Text</span></p>
<p><span class="copy">More Text</span></p>
<p><span class="copy">Even More Text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

u can also use onclick like

```js
 function copyCode() {
  const Code = document.querySelector("input");
  Code.select();
  document.execCommand("copy", false);
}
```

```html
<input type="input"  />
<button onclick={copyCode()}>Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers I have found here seem to be outdated. You should use the clipboard API instead of execCommand.
This code should work:

```
    let textString = document.querySelector('span.textstring').textContent; //Get value of the string you want to copy
    const copyText = async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(textString);
            console.log('Content copied to clipboard!');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Copy failed!');
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('span.textstring').addEventListener('click', copyText); //Add the event handler click, so when the span is clicked, the value is copied
```

Inspired and adapted by: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copy-text-to-clipboard-javascript/

Answer (score -4):

```js
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
```

```html
<p onclick="copy(this)">hello man</p>
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of another answer except that you've removed the explanation

Comment: Can use this solution to copy a string to the clipboard.

Comment: It worked super for me, but if you copied it from elsewhere, I would love to credit the brilliant mind that has given us this excellent answer.