# Copy element content to clipboard on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, clipboard

Is there a way to copy to clipboard an element content by clicking on other element?

I saw lots of related problems, but I don't like the approach of using function.

since the data is from the database.

here's my sample code.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/ZrRXwo)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click .copy").click(function(){
      $(this).closest("click").find("span").text();
      document.execCommand("Copy");
  });
 });
```

```css
.click{
  padding: 10px;
}
.click .copy{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 12px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -2px;
width: 80px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #f7cc83;
display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.click:hover .copy{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">
  <div class="copy">copy text</div>
  <span>copy this text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="click">
  <div class="copy">copy text</div>
  <span>copy this text 2</span>
</div>
<div class="click">
  <div class="copy">copy text</div>
  <span>copy this text 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: I saw that, but I don't like to use that approach, the answer is too complicated

Comment: Don't look at the accepted answer on that question, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905277/2181514 is only 1 or 2 lines than you have already.

Comment: Try this one, it's more specific to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071478/2181514

Comment: Ok sir thank you, Im sorry also..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not use .click and instead used click as the element. You could debug this by seeing the init method of the jquery not being able to find the element based on the criteria.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click .copy").click(function(event){
    var $tempElement = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($tempElement);
        $tempElement.val($(this).closest(".click").find("span").text()).select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        $tempElement.remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.click{
  padding: 10px;
}
.click .copy{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 12px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -2px;
width: 80px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #f7cc83;
display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.click:hover .copy{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">
  <div class="copy">copy text</div>
  <span>copy this text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="click">
  <div class="copy">copy text</div>
  <span>copy this text 2</span>
</div>
<div class="click">
  <div class="copy">copy text</div>
  <span>copy this text 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery/30905277#30905277)

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">P1: I am paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p2">P2: I am a second paragraph</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy P1</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy P2</button>
<br/><br/><input type="text" placeholder="Paste here for test" />
```

Comment: In addition, you can also call it with a selector, like this: copyToClipboard($('.mydiv')); You don't need to pass the ID necessarily.