# copy text to clipboard using .select() getting Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow this code:   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

HTML Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">App Link</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input id="appID" value="123"></input>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copyBtn">Copy</button>
            </div>                  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
var copyBtn = document.getElementById('copyBtn');

copyBtn.onclick = function(){
    var myCode = document.getElementById('appID').value;
    var fullLink = document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(fullLink);
    fullLink.value = "http://fulllink/" + myCode;
    fullLink.select();
    document.execCommand("copy", false);
    fullLink.remove();
    alert("Copied the text: " + fullLink.value);
}
```

Code will not work when input and button are inside the modal; code will work if placed in the body. Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are receiving the error because `.select` is a function bound to input elements. You're currently trying to call select on your `fullLink` string. We need to create an input element and give it your value. Something like this:

```js
var copyBtn = document.getElementById('copyBtn');
copyBtn.onclick = function(){
    var myCode = document.getElementById('appID').value;
    var fullLink = document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(fullLink);
    fullLink.value = "http://fulllink/" + myCode;
    fullLink.select();
    document.execCommand("copy", false);
    fullLink.remove();
    alert("Copied the text: " + fullLink.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="appID" value="123"></input>
<button id="copyBtn">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Fixed the answer as the element has to be bound to the DOM for the `document.execCommand()` to find it. Interesting, but makes sense. I found that tip low down in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071444/5790134 thanks to user prasanth

Comment: Thank you. This works when in Body, but does not work when input and button is placed inside a modal. I updated my post with your code and updated issue.

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out. I appended the input element inside the modal, and it works: 

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.appendChild(fullLink);

Answer (score 1):

It's happens because your var `fullLink` is not a DOM node but a simple text. Function `select` defined for DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete `tabindex="-1"` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

A very elegant way of doing it would be by creating a text area element, that would allow us to take advantage of the .select function.

JS code:

```
function copyStringToClipboard (str) {
   // Create new element
   var el = document.createElement('textarea');
   // Set value (string to be copied)
   el.value = str;
   // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
   el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
   el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
   document.body.appendChild(el);
   // Select text inside element
   el.select();
   // Copy text to clipboard
   document.execCommand('copy');
   // Remove temporary element
   document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

Example of the function being called:

```
copyStringToClipboard("abc123");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem,try this code

```
$('#copyBtn').click(function() {
 var text=$('#appID').text();
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
});
```