# Copy text from a div to clipboard using document.execCommand in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I am attempting to copy text from a `div` after the URL is shortened.

I have placed a `ref` value in the `div` that will render the shortend URL. But, I am getting error:

> TypeError: inputArea.input.select() is not a function.

I am not sure how to reference the text within the div.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Shorten = () => {
        
    const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState('');
    const inputArea = useRef(null);
        
    function copyLink(e){
        inputArea.current.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        e.target.focus();
        setCopySuccess('Copied!');
    };
 
    {isPending && <div className="loading-text">Loading...</div>}
    {shortLink && <div ref={inputArea} className="shorten-text">{shortLink}</div>}
    <hr></hr>
    <div>
      <button className="shorten-it" onClick={copyLink} >Copy</button>
      {copySuccess}
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) function is only available for `input` or `textarea` elements. It is not available for [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991534/2873538).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) will get **deprecated** in favor of the modern [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) to interact with [clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard).

Here is how to use **Clipboard** API:

```
function updateClipboard(newClip) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(newClip).then(
    () => {
      setCopySuccess("Copied!");
    },
    () => {
      setCopySuccess("Copy failed!");
    }
  );
}

function copyLink() {
  navigator.permissions
    .query({ name: "clipboard-write" })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.state === "granted" || result.state === "prompt") {
        updateClipboard(inputArea.current?.innerText);
      }
    });
}
```

Notes about using [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#using_the_clipboard_api):

> The Clipboard API adds greater **flexibility**, in that you **aren't limited** to copying the current selection into the clipboard, but can directly specify what information to place into the clipboard.

> Using the API requires that you have the **permission** "clipboardRead" or "clipboardWrite" in your manifest.json file.

> The clipboard-write permission is granted **automatically** to pages when they are in the active tab. The clipboard-read permission must be requested, which you can do by trying to read data from the clipboard.

> [Clipboard API (clipboard-write permission) is currently not supported by Firefox but supported by Chrome / Chromium](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1560373)

---

Or, to use `Document.execCommand`, you should convert the `div` into an `input` or `textarea` (which can be selected) and use CSS to make it look like a div:

```
function copyLink(e) {
  inputArea.current?.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  e.target.focus();
  setCopySuccess("Copied!");
}

// ...

{shortLink && (
  <input
    ref={inputArea}
    type="text"
    className="shorten-text"
    value={shortLink}
  />
)}
```

Or, see [How to copy text from a div to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639681/2873538) if you still want to use `div`.

Comment: Thanks I tried the first solution and it gave me a permission error, so I updated the div to be an input field and it worked. I will need to read more on how the Clipboard API works.

Comment: I tested `Clipboard API` on chrome. It worked and gave me **no** permission error because write permission is automatically granted. But I think currently it is **best** to use `Document.execCommand` and later migrate to `Clipboard API` when it would be supported by more browsers.

Comment: Ok got it I am using Firefox for development maybe the permission issue