# Copy to clipboard with react

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to copy text to clipboard when user clicks on an html element in react. So far I've only seen solutions for html & Javascript, but none of them related to just react. For example, using query selectors.
So I'm mapping through an array to provide text: whenever  a user clicks on that mapped element, i want to copy to clipboard.
Like so:

```
const array = ['Email', 'Phone', 'Address']
const arrayrow = array.map(el=>{
 return <p onClick={()=>copyToClipboard()}>
 {el}
</p>
 })
```

So just wondering how i should go about writing this function.

```
function copyToClipboard(){}
```

Comment: You already have access to the value for each `p` when you are mapping, so just pass the value in to your function? `() => copyToClipboard(el)` - what specifically about `react` are you having a problem with?

Comment: Just avoiding query selectors because I know there a way of doing it in javascript, but not sure if there is a 'react' way of doing it

Comment: [Copy text from a div to clipboard using document.execCommand in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032810/2873538)

Comment: The parameter passed down to   navigator.clipboard.writeText(newClip), would be the text? IF so, how come i am getting an error?