# How would I link a copy button to a cell in a table?

Tags: html, button, html-table

I have a copy button script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var copyText = table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied");
}
```

And my table:

```
<table id="myTable">
{% for resp in results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ resp }}</td>
            <td>{{ resp.Question_id.Statement }}</td>
            <td><button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I want the button to copy the text inside td {{ resp }} /td

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071478/1964336

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(val, event) {
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = val;
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy', false);
  inp.remove();
  alert('copied');
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction('one')">Copy text</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction('two')">Copy text</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction('three')">Copy text</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction('four')">Copy text</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

a quick solution will be passing the `text` (to be copied) with in the function as argu. 
`ctrl + v` to see the result.

Comment: it works when i put in a variable like 'reponse'. But what if the variable i want to copy is in this format {{ resp }}

Comment: <td><button onclick="myFunction(resp)">Copy text</button></td>

try passing resp directly.

Comment: tried myFunction(resp) and myFunction('{{ resp }}'), both don't work

Comment: what frontend are you using?

Comment: i am using django as the front end

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it in Djando as I never worked on it but I code in angularjs and it seem like working.
https://codepen.io/jatinderbhola/pen/vaJPee?editors=1010#0

can you share a codepan/ fiddle code so that I can look into it.

Comment: it seems to work for some of the {{ resp }} but not all. If {{ resp }} is one line it works but if it has linebreaks in it it does not. is there a way around this?

Comment: can you share what resp look like?

Comment: Using the function you have given, how would i replace <br> tags with linebreaks and <p> tags with ""?