# Copy text to clipboard from div with javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm trying to copy the text from the next div to the clipboard with `Javascript`. Below is my current code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hl7MsgBox">
    <span class="boxspan">1</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">2</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">3</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">4</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">5</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">6</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">7</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">8</span>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".btnFileCopy").click(function () {
    var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("hl7MsgBox");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

I'm expecting to get the new output when I paste it into the `notepad`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

However, for some reason, it's not working and throw the next error message :

> Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function ...

Does anyone know how could I solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - copy text string on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071353/javascript-copy-text-string-on-click)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, some reference:

> The `getElementsByClassName()` method of Document interface returns an **array-like object** of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call `getElementsByClassName()` on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

So, in your particular case, the `copyText` variable will hold an array of elements (those that have the class `hl7MsgBox` under the document element). Now, because in your case there is only one element with that class, you can access it using `copyText[0]` and get all the text wrapped by it with `copyText[0].textContent`. In summary, you can do something like next to get the text to be copied:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hl7MsgBox");
var copyText = elems[0].textContent;
```

Another possibility is to use the method [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the **first Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

With the `querySelector()` method you can simply do:

```
var copyText = document.querySelector(".hl7MsgBox").textContent;
```

Finally, we can create a general method called `copyToClipBoard()` whose only job is to copy the received `string` to the clipboard an rearrange the code with pure `Javascript` like this:

```js
const copyToClipBoard = (str) =>
{
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
};

document.querySelector(".btnCopy").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var copyText = document.querySelector(".hl7MsgBox").textContent;

    // Or...
    //var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hl7MsgBox");
    //var copyText = elems[0].textContent;

    copyToClipBoard(copyText);
});
```

```html
<div class="hl7MsgBox">
    <span class="boxspan">1</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">2</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">3</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">4</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">5</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">6</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">7</span>
    <br>
    <span class="boxspan">8</span>
</div>
<button class="btnCopy">Copy To Clipboard</button>
<br>
<textarea rows=8 cols=50 placeholder="Paste text here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: FYI, a more complete and general copyToClipboard function can be found here:

https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f

Answer (score 3):

Simply get the text from the DIV and pass it into this function.

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
        // IE specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
        return clipboardData.setData("Text", text); 

    } else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.textContent = text;
        textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.select();
        try {
            return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        } catch (ex) {
            console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
            return false;
        } finally {
            document.body.removeChild(textarea);
        }
    }
}   

copyToClipboard('hello'); //hello
```

Comment: The only piece of code that worked for me. Great stuff here @Diego Fortes