# Copy Wordpress Title in backend

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

So, I have a CPT and I have added some Custom Columns in the backend. I have this button at the side and it should copy the title. I was using Javascript for this and it is not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("clickTitle");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
.click-title{
display: none;
}
```

```html
echo the_title( '<h4 class="click-title" id="clickTitle">', '</h4>' );
echo '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="copyFunction()">Copy Title</button>';
```

But it is not working. I want the button to copy the title and I can't find a way to do that. I tried more than that.

[(Click here to view image) I want to copy the title when I click Copy Title button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2rHe.png)

Comment: See [Javascript - copy text string on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071353/)

Comment: I guess better you can use this js.. https://clipboardjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only works on input text field elements

So, set a `input` hidden field next to your title.

```js
function copyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("clickTitle");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert(copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<h4 class="click-title">This is the title to be copied.</h4>
<input id="clickTitle" type="text" value="This is the title to be copied">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="copyFunction()">Copy Title</button>
```

**To work inside a loop, a little change should be done.**

Give a unique ID for each input field:

```
<input id="clickTitle-<?php echo $post_id; ?>" type="text" value="This is the title to be copied">
```

Call the method by passing the desired ID:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="copyFunction(<?php echo $post_id; ?>)">Copy Title</button>
```

Then update the function to look for the right id.

```
function copyFunction( elId ) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("clickTitle-" + elId );
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer. But I have a slight problem. Since my input field will have value=" ' . get_the_title( $post_id ) . ". All the buttons are copying the first title. So, do I have to loop the function? Because the copied text should be the title. But I am getting the same title as the first.

Comment: Hey man, this is working. So, really thank you very much. Appreciate a lot. If any other things come on the way. I'm gonna tell you. Thank you again. See ya.