# How can I copy text in a specific code block to the clipboard on button click with HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to copy the text stored in a specific code block in a list item to the clipboard when a user clicks a button. I've found various methods online that allow you to copy when you click something, but I want to be able to do all of this on the page if possible.

For example, I will have a list of items as follows:

- Click this page.
- Type this code:

  ```
   <Code Sample>
  ```

I would like to have a button that copies the code for that specific line item.

I've had success copying text using the solution provided in this other [Stackoverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071444/10139207), but that doesn't work if I'm wanting to have a button click copy text **OTHER** than what is stored in the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Answer (score 1):

If you can place something with an id for example around the code blocks, you could do this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Click this page.</li>
    <li>
        Type this code:
        <div id="code">[Code Sample]</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button">Copy</button>
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const code = document.getElementById('code');
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(code.innerHTML);
});
```