# How to copy a text, using onclick html button?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, copy

I create my own portfolio website, on the navigation bar, there is my email.
I want anybody cliking on this email will copy it to the clipboard.
That's what i tried but it's not working !

```
<button onclick="copy()" id="copy">Copy</button>

function copy() {
var copyText = document.querySelector("#copy"); 
copyText.select(); document.execCommand("copy");}
document.querySelector("#copy").addEventListener("click", copy);
```

Comment: It looks like somebody else [has also asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dcopy+text+to+clipboard).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Buttons do not have a select method, text boxes do.
You can use a text input to hold the email address to copy to the clipboard.

```js
function copy() {
  var copyText = document.querySelector("#email"); 
  copyText.select(); document.execCommand("copy");
}
document.querySelector("#copy").addEventListener("click", copy);
```

```css
input {margin:-100%}
```

```html
<button onclick="copy()" id="copy">Copy</button>
<input id=email value="email@so.com">
```

Buttons do not have a select method, textboxes have it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use [execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). It has been **deprecated**, browsers still support it for now, but not in the future.

For a better solution, You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75721119/21388320

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is an ability to "request permission" and test for access to the clipboard via the permissions API in Chrome 66.

```
var text = "text to be copied"
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(_ => {
  console.log('copied successfully!')
})
```